# Prove: $\sin (\alpha - \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \beta \cos \alpha$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

This is an exercise in Gelfand's Trigonometry, It is not that difficult but I am doing something wrong that is preventing me from proving the identity.

We need to use the following diagram to prove it: [image]

**My attempt:**

$$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\sin (\alpha - \beta) = \frac{CD}{AC} \\
= \frac{PQ}{AC} \\
= \frac{BQ - BP}{AC} \\
= \frac{BQ}{AC} - \frac{BP}{AC} \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Now in the following step we should use an intermediary to make this equal to the required identity, but for the first fraction I can't find anything rather than $AB$}
$$
= \frac{BQ}{AB} \cdot \frac{AB}{AC} \\
$$
My problem here is I don't see how $\frac{AB}{AC}$ would simplify to $\cos \beta$ to me this seems like $\sec \beta$ How could this be fixed?

Comment: The reason this approach ($\frac{BQ}{AC} - \frac{BP}{AC}$) doesn't yield what you want, is because it will not yield what you want.. E.g. let $AB = 1$, then $BQ = \sin \alpha, AC  = \cos \beta$, there is no way to make $ BQ / AC = BC \times AC $

Comment: Note that for the other fraction, you get 
$$
\frac{BP}{AC} = \frac{BP}{BC}\cdot \frac{BC}{AC} = \cos(\alpha-\beta)\tan(\beta)
$$So 1) both terms want you to multiply by $\cos\beta$ or $\cos^2\beta$ to get rid of denominators, and 2) you have probably taken a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: So it seems like my approach was wrong from the beginning. Perhaps you could provide me a hint for this one? I tried using $\sin (\alpha) = \sin([\alpha-\beta]+\beta)$, and solve the equation for $\sin(\alpha - \beta)$, but that wasn't useful either.

Comment: An approach I have in mind is to use the fact that $\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin (\alpha + (-\beta)$, and take advantage of the sine function being odd. But that doesn't use the diagram in any way.

Comment: The correct approach is to use areas. I'll try to post a solution within an hour.

Comment: Please refer to this diagram provided by @Blue, it's my personal favorite:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry/1342#1342

Comment: Areas? Interesting. I know how to prove it using the cosine law, Ptolemy's theorem, the famous constructive proof, and the one I mentioned above. I'm just struggling with this diagram.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving sine difference formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929573/deriving-sine-difference-formula)

Comment: My last comment may have given poor advice. I know how to use another diagram to the same end, but I've been unable to adapt the strategy to this one. I recommend @Vasya's  solution instead, although the angles will need to be relabelled.

Comment: @J.G. I'm still interested in seeing the proof by areas, I hope you can post it.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Not really, but thanks for the effort nonetheless.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I agree that technically this is a duplicate. However I think it would be a disservice to the community to close *this* copy because it’s clearly of such a higher quality.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Agreed. I retract the vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you like this or not. Let $AC=1$. Then in $rt\Delta ACD$, 
$$ \sin(\alpha-\beta)=CD=PQ=BQ-BP.$$
In $rt\Delta ABC$, $AC=AB\cos\beta$ and hence $AB=\frac1{\cos\beta}, BC=\tan\beta.$
So in $rt\Delta ABQ$, 
$$BQ=AB\sin\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}.$$
Also in $rt\Delta BPC$, $\angle PBC=\alpha-\beta$ and hence
$$ BP=BC\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\tan\beta\cos(\alpha-\beta). $$
So one has
$$ \sin(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}-\tan\beta\cos(\alpha-\beta). \tag{1}$$
Similarly
$$ \cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}+\tan\beta\sin(\alpha-\beta). \tag{2}$$
Putting (2) in (1), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin(\alpha-\beta)&=&\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}-\tan\beta\cos(\alpha-\beta)\\
&=&\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}-\tan\beta\left(\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}+\tan\beta\sin(\alpha-\beta)\right)\\
&=&\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos^2\beta}-\tan^2\beta\sin(\alpha-\beta)
\end{eqnarray}
or
$$(1+\tan^2\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos^2\beta} $$
or
$$ \sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta. $$

Comment: This is probably it. I avoided this approach since it doesn't duplicate Gelfand's method of proving the sum identity, but it looks like there's no way around. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This website has a lot of cool stuff about trigonometry.

https://trigonography.com/2015/09/28/angle-sum-and-difference-for-sine-and-cosine/
[image]

Comment: I add that trigonography site has been created by Blue who is very active on Math Stack Exchange.